# Como hago para cambiar de formulario sin que se note ese parpadeo Windows form c#

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero es saber como podría yo cambiar de un formulario a otro sin que se note ese parpadeo que hace al clicar el botón.

```
private void iconButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Home home = new Home();
    home.Show();
    this.Hide();   
}
```

Ese es el código que utilizo para cambiar de formularios y al mismo tiempo ocultar el formulario al cambiar a otro. Quiero cambiar de formularios pero que no parpadee al cambiar, que sea un cambio mas suave.

Comment: Hola Dari, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Listo ya lo edite

Comment: Pon los colores de fondo iguales para que no se note https://stackoverflow.com/a/23059420/13419694